# Vue.js what directory to build the production from on EC2 Ubuntu?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am a little confused about where to build vue.js for production.

In my dev folder on ubuntu 16.04 -

1. I start the project
2. Update my files in the src directory
3. Then do npm build  ( I have tried form both the project home page where index.html lives and the src directory)
4. In the dist directory I see that a new index.html and a static folder is created.
5. Deploy the contents of my dist directory to my public directory where normally index.html will live.

Result:  I can see the page title but not the contents.  My code works fine the dev environment.  I am trying not to run it from S3